# get list of points on diagonal between 2 points in python 2d list

Tags: python, math, multidimensional-array

For a given square 2d list, say:

```
foo2d = [
[1, 1, 1, 1, 3],
[1, 3, 0, 3, 4],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 3],
[1, 3, 0, 2, 4],
[1, 3, 1, 3, 4]
]
```

I would like a list of the diagonals from (0, 1) (`foo2d[1][0]`) to the point diagonal from it, (2, 3) (`foo2d[3][2]`). So in the toy list above, the returned list should be: `[1, 0, 1]`

I have tried taking advantage of the fact that the slope of that line is 1 (or -1), so an element on the list would have to satisfy:

```
     pointY - startY
abs(-----------------) == 1
     pointX - startX
```

and be between the x minimum and x maximum. I don't have the code implementation because a) it broke everything and b) my computer crashed just as I was saving the file, forcing me to revert to a git backup that did not contain that code.

If you need it, I can try to write some pseudo code for this behavior. Thanks for any thoughts you can give me with this issue!

Comment: Would like using numpy ?

Comment: @WeNYoBen Well... I don't /want/ to restructure my program for it, and it seems like it might be more hassle than it's worth. I'd much prefer vanilla python, but if I must, I must.

Comment: you want to print all the points on diagonal between 2 points? so the slope of line can only be 1 or -1? or any value?

Comment: @recnac Think how a queen moves on chessboard. I feel so stupid that I forgot -1, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the slop of line only can be 1 or -1, you can try this:

```
def get_diagonal_points(matrix, start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y):
    # make start_x <= end_x, if you don't need to check, remove this line
    if start_x > end_x:
        start_x, start_y, end_x, end_y = end_x, end_y, start_x, start_y

    result = []
    slope = (end_y - start_y) // (end_x - start_x)
    for i, j in zip(range(start_x, end_x), range(start_y, end_y, slope)):
        result.append(matrix[i][j])
    result.append(matrix[end_x][end_y])  # add end point
    return result
```

test and output:

```
foo2d = [
[1, 1, 1, 1, 3],
[1, 3, 0, 3, 4],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 3],
[1, 3, 0, 2, 4],
[1, 3, 1, 3, 4]
]
print(get_diagonal_points(foo2d, 0, 1, 2, 3))
# [1, 0, 1]
print(get_diagonal_points(foo2d, 0, 4, 3, 1))
# [3, 3, 1, 3]
print(get_diagonal_points(foo2d, 3, 1, 0, 4))
# [3, 3, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for this response. I've never actually understood what the zip function does? Can you explain it please?

Comment: [zip](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip) pack iterators and traverse them together @WarpDriveEnterprises

Comment: you can simply understand it as `for` two `range` at the same time. @WarpDriveEnterprises